# Static Functions and class variables?

Tags: c++, function, static

I have broken down my issue into a small simple program.

I have a class `myclass` I have created in a separate .cpp file "classes.cpp" and declared in the header file "classes.h".  `myclass` contains a variable `a` of which is initialized when instantiated.  This makes variable `a = 5`.

My overall goal is to create a class in a separate .cpp file declared in a .h file which I can create multiple instances of in my `main()` program.  The problem I am having is this.

In my `main()` function I create an instance of `myclass` called `first`.
my main program shows the variable `a` is set to the number 5.
If I want to change that number using a static function (and it has to be a static function as this relates to something much bigger in another program I am writing).  I call the static function directly and in that static_function I create an instance of `myclass` and call the non_static_function because static functions have no implicit 'this' connecting them to an object.

In my non_static_function I change the value to the number 8.  The problem is  that the value of variable 'a' in 'first' remains at 5 when I want it to be 8.  I need to change the value using `first->static_function(8)` **and not by** `first->a = 8`.  .  How can I do this?

Code below:

```
**main.cpp**
#include <iostream>
#include "classes.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    myclass *first = new myclass();
    cout << "Myclass variable a is = " << first->a << endl;

    first->static_function(8); // trying to change myclass variable 'a' to 8.

    cout << "But" << endl;
    cout << "the actual value of a is still: " << first->a << endl;
}

**classes.h**
#ifndef CLASSES_H_INCLUDED
#define CLASSES_H_INCLUDED
class myclass
{
public:
    int a;
    myclass();

    void non_static_function(int x);
    static void static_function(int x);

};
#endif // CLASSES_H_INCLUDED

**classes.cpp**
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "classes.h"

using namespace std;

myclass::myclass()
{
    a = 5;
}

void myclass::non_static_function(int x)
{
    a = x;
    cout << "The value for variable 'a' was 5 but is now: " << a << endl;
}

void myclass::static_function(int x)
{
    myclass *p = new myclass();
    p->non_static_function(x);
}
```

Comment: You can't change a non-static field with a static method, unless you pass in the instance (`first`) that you want to change.

Comment: That's why you create an instance of that object in your static function and call a non_static function.  As far as I know the non_static_function should be able to change the class value (and I'm not sure why it won't reflect in the instance "first".

Comment: `p` in `static_function` immediately goes out of scope at the end of the function, so it won't affect anything. Keep in mind that the `p` created in `static_function` is completely separate from any other instance that you create, like `first`. Changing anything about `p` will have 0 affect on `first`. Be careful using `new`,  you shouldn't use it like you are. You're never calling delete on it, so it will never free the space you requested (that doesn't happen automatically like in java). As a general rule you should really never use `new` outside of a constructor.

Comment: If you expect `a` to be modifiable from anywhere, you should just make it a static field, instead of an instance field.

Comment: "Changing anything about p will have 0 affect on first.".  I think that's the key point.  But p is just there to call a non_static function (I don't care how it is instantiated).  I just need the definition of the non_static_function to change a class value.  non_static_function is definitely called as you can see from the output.    However I think you have made a key point as mentioned above.   So... is there a way to change the variable 'a' for all instances of "myclass" ?

Comment: No, unless you create your own factory that keeps references of all the instantiated `MyClass`s, you can't use 1 function to change every non-static field. And `a` isn't really a "class value" (which suggests that it's static), it's an instance variable. If you need 1 `a` value that can be changed from anywhere, you want it to be static; then every instance will share the single variable. Note that this isn't really the best option if you can avoid it though; it can lead to confusing, fragile code later. This might indicate that you need to refactor your design.

Answer (score 2):

If you want every instance of `myclass` to have its own `a` and you want to call a static function to change it then you need to pass the instance you want changed to the static function.  A static function can only modify static members of a class or the members of an instance that is inside its scope.  Non static member functions can change any variable that is a member of the class.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int bar;
public:
    static void static_function(int value, Foo & foo) { foo.bar = value; }
    void non_static_function(int value) { bar = value; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Foo::static_function(8, foo);
    // now bar will have the value of 8
    foo.non_static_function(20);
    // now bar will have the value of 20
}
```

Comment: It almost seems like he needs `a` itself to be static; although I'm not sure that's the best design choice.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I agree that the OP shouldn't do this but I wanted to demonstrate how they could if they needed to.

Comment: Still a good point Nathan.  Now what if I am not calling my static function from main().  What if that call is made from another class in a separate .cpp file?   I somehow need to take the instance I instantiated in main() and use it in the definition of another class to change a value in "myclass" ?

Comment: @Svetsi You have to somehow pass the instance to it.  How else would the static function know which instance to change?  You could have the other class take a shared pointer to the instance or you could have it take a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a way to deal with this small problem.  Above the 'myclass' definition in classes.cpp I declare a 'myclass' variable 
**myclass *tgt;**  . Then in my constructor for 'myclass' I just allocate the instantiated object to a my global myclass variable of which I can access from the myclass definition **tgt = this;**   Now I can use tgt in my static function to call the non_static_function in my 'myclass' definition and it all works perfectly.

**NathanOliver**, you are correct in saying that I need a class instance but the way I have done it here suits my needs.  Passing the instance of myclass is certainly another way of doing this but it would require a global function above my 'myclass' definition.

Thanks for the help.

```
    **main.cpp**
    #include <iostream>
    #include "classes.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

         myclass *first = new myclass();
 cout << "Myclass variable a is = " << first->a << endl;

 first->non_static_function(8); // trying to change myclass variable 'a' to 8.

cout << "But" << endl;
cout << "The actual value of a is still: " << first->a << endl;

myclass *second = new myclass();
cout << "For the 'second' class the variable a is: " << second->a << endl;
second->non_static_function(23);
cout << "After calling the static function from 'second' the value of a is: " << second->a << endl;
cout << "And first->a is still: " << first->a << endl;
    }



    **classes.h**
    #ifndef CLASSES_H_INCLUDED
    #define CLASSES_H_INCLUDED
    class myclass
    {
    public:
        int a;
        myclass();

        void non_static_function(int x);
        static void static_function(int x);

    };
    #endif // CLASSES_H_INCLUDED





    **classes.cpp**
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include "classes.h"

    using namespace std;

    myclass *tgt;  // *Add a global myclass variable above the myclass 
      definition*

    myclass::myclass()
    {
       tgt = this;  // *In the constructor allocate the instantiated class
   //from main() to "tgt" .*
        a = 5;
    }

    void myclass::non_static_function(int x)
    {
        a = x;
    // Now see that the value of a is changed.
   cout << "The value for variable 'a' was 5 but is now: "<< this->a << endl;
    }

    void myclass::static_function(int x)
    {
        tgt->non_static_function(x);
    }
```

Comment: Actually, I concede that my solution only solves part of the problem.  If I make multiple instances of myclass the functionality of the two instances clash under certain circumstances.   My question is thus evolving.        Would anyone know how to keep track of multiple instances of myclass so that when I access each instance the changes only occur in the class I have accessed?  I'm thinking a static counter and a vector or a map but I'm not sure.  There must be a standard way of doing this?